# Furthest point from polygon/point

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, vector, distance

I want to calculate distance between smaller dots (they represent towns, villages etc.) and these larger red dots (capital cities of admin. region).
My goal is to show wich location is the furthest from the capital city for each region.

[image]

What tool/plugin is best to do it? I was trying with 'HUB distances' but it doesn't work properly I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through the `Vector` -> `Distance Matrix` tool in QGIS. One of Ujaval Ghandi's excellent QGIS tutorials explains exactly how to do so here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html